# Angularjs Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Hello I'm making a code to study in angularjs and found the error.

> Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.4/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=cursostable%20in%20cursos%20%7C%20filter%3ApesquisaCurso&p1=object%3A3&p2=%7B%22codigo%22%3A45434%2C%22descricao%22%3A%22java%20web%22%2C%22datahorario%22%3A%22Segundas%20e%20Sextas%2C%2019hrs%22%2C%22professor%22%3A%7B%22codigo%22%3A1%2C%22nome%22%3A%22asasasasasa%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22asasasas%40hotmail.com%22%2C%22fone%22%3A%222323232323%22%7D%2C%22%24%24hashKey%22%3A%22object%3A3%22%7D

in console This error prevents me from entering new record

code below:

html

```
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="professor" class="col-sm-1">Professor</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="curso.professor"ng-model="curso.professor" 
    ng-options="professor.nome for professor in professores track by professor.codigo">
         </select>
          </div>
                    </div>

    <button type="button" ng-click="salvar()" ng-disabled="!curso.codigo || !curso.descricao || !curso.datahorario || !curso.professor" class="btn btn-success">Cadastrar</button>
```

controller

```
 cursoModulo.controller("cursoController", function($scope){
    $scope.professores = [
        {codigo: 1, nome: 'asasasasasa', email: 'asasasas@hotmail.com', fone:'2323232323'},
    ];

    $scope.cursos = [
        {codigo: 45434, descricao: 'java web', datahorario: 'Segundas e Sextas, 19hrs', professor: {codigo: 1, nome: 'asasasasasa', email: 'asasasas@hotmail.com', fone:'2323232323'}},
    ];

    $scope.selecionaCurso = function(cursoSelecionado){
        $scope.curso = cursoSelecionado;
    }

    $scope.limparCampo = function(){
        $scope.curso = null;
    }

    $scope.salvar = function(){
        $scope.cursos.push($scope.curso);
        $scope.limparCampo();
    }

    $scope.excluir = function(){
        $scope.cursos.splice($scope.cursos.indexOf($scope.curso),1);
        $scope.limparCampo();
    }
```

Comment: provide code on plunker

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, new record has a such "codigo" that already presents in the "professores" list. Rememeber that all records in angular collections **must have uniq field that you define in "track by" expression**

Comment: In other words try 'track by $index' instead of 'track by professor.codigo'

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if you are using angular version < 1.2.0

Change your version to (minimum of) 1.2 and it will work, since "track by" was introduced in that version.

Your code work on this fiddle (jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/1370) with angular 1.6.4

Comment: my angular version is 1.6.4 :)

Comment: Its weird but your code work on this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/JKBbV/1370/) with angular 1.6.4

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS does not allow duplicates in a `ng-repeat` directive.

That means whatever you are writing in `track by` should be unique so try  `track by $index` instead of `track by professor.codigo` as said by rrd.

Working [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGxnRXpRwpNDb85L0v5E?p=preview)

Source: [click here!](http://www.anujgakhar.com/2013/06/15/duplicates-in-a-repeater-are-not-allowed-in-angularjs/)